# Moving one line in PuTTY console with Ctrl + Shift + arrow keys

Tags: console, putty

Recently I started using vim to development and since that time I'm only using PuTTY instead of NXNoMachine (with GNOME).

When looking up huge console logs I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> a lot to move up/down one screen and I'm used to using one line movement (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>) as well.

Unfortunately one line movement doesn't work in PuTTY.
Any idea how to make PuTTY allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

See [Scrolling the screen back](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-scrollback) section in PuTTY documentation.